# Convert string to an attribute for a nested object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to access a string `"key1.key2"` as properties of an object.
For example :

```
var obj = { key1 : {key2 : "value1", key3 : "value2"}};
var attr_string = "key1.key2";
```

The variable `attr_string` is a string of attributes in a nested object joined by `"."`. It can be of any depth like `"key1.key2.key3.key4..."`

I want something like `obj.attr_string` to give the value of `obj["key1"]["key2"]` that is `"value1"`

How to achieve this?

Comment: A combination of two anti-patterns: `with (obj) var result = eval(attr);`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)

Comment: Please read: ['There is no such thing as a "JSON object"'](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). What you have is a normal JavaScript object.

Comment: @dfsq I dont get it. `eval(attr)` will give "Reference Error for key1" Can you please explain more clearly?

Comment: @ManuKMohan `eval(attr_string);`

Comment: I say it again: What you have is **not** JSON. I won't start an edit war though.

Comment: @dfsq `eval(attr_string)` gives "Reference Error for key1" .

Comment: You forgot `with` probably?

Comment: And note that using `with` will throw an error in strict mode. I wouldn't recommend using it. Have a look at the question I linked to, it contains the solution you seek.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks a lot for your valuable info :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @dfsq for remembering me the use of `eval`.

Here is what I was expecting, a simple way to evaluate the objects string attribute.

```
var obj = { key1 : {key2 : "value1", key3 : "value2"}};
var attr_string = "key1.key2";

var result = eval("obj."+attr_string);
```

There is no need of splitting the string with `"."` and then putting it in a loop to get the value. `eval` can evaluate any string with javascript code statement.

**Be noted:** although the code functions as expected, `eval` ***should not be used!!!***

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!.

Comment: NEVER USE EVAL!!! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!

Answer (score 0):

```
var target = obj;
const parts = attr_string.split(".");
for (var part in parts)
  target = target[part[part]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

```
var obj = { key1: { key2A: 'x', key2B: { key3: 'y' } } },
    attr_string = 'key1.key2B.key3',

    find = function ( obj, str ) {

        var index = 0,
            arr = str.split( '.' );

        if ( arr.length ) {
            while ( typeof obj === 'object' &&  arr[ index ] in obj ) {
                obj = obj[ arr[ index ] ];
                index++;
            }
        }

        return obj;

    };


find( obj, attr_string ); // Returns 'y'
```

Answer (score 0):

fixing up @John's answer into a re-usable function (which I will be using myself)

```
function nested(obj, attrString){
    var path = attrString.split(".");
    for (var i in path){
        obj = obj[path[i]];
    }
    return obj;
}

// test it out...
x = {a:{b:{c:"happy days"}}};
console.log(nested(x, 'a'));
console.log(nested(x, 'a.b'));
console.log(nested(x, 'a.b.c'));
```